# ffmpeg does not make a video from my images

Tags: ffmpeg

I've currently got some images that I'd like to display in the form of a movie. So, I pocked around a bit and found ffmpeg. This is the tutorial I have been going with:

http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/09/27/read-and-write-video-frames-in-python-using-ffmpeg/

Since I don't care about reading, I skipped right to the writing section. As far as I can tell, this is what my program should say:

```py
import subprocess as sp
FFMPEG_BIN = "ffmpeg" #I'm on Ubuntu
command = [ FFMPEG_BIN,
            '-y',
            '-f', 'rawvideo',
            '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
            '-s', '1000x1000',
            '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24',
            '-r', '24',
            '-i', '-',
            '-an',
            '-vcodec', 'mpeg',
            'my_output_videofile.mp4' ]


pipe = sp.Popen( command, stdin = sp.PIPE, stderr = sp.PIPE)
```

However, when I run this in spyder, I get the error message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/xander/Downloads/python-meep/makeVideo.py", line 15, in <module>
    pipe = sp.Popen( command, stdin = sp.PIPE, stderr = sp.PIPE )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
  OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Why is that happening? I'm really suspicious: I never mention the names of my pictures ("Image0.jpeg", "Image1.jpeg", ..., "Image499.jpeg", "Image500.jpeg"). Any help will be greatly appreciated!

P.S. The guy in the tutorial also says that some codecs require a bitrate; I tried that and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `-i` argument you are only specifying `'-'` and the script is looking for an image named as such.

try:

```
from subprocess import call
command = [ FFMPEG_BIN,
        '-i', './image%d.jpg',
        '-y',
        '-f', 'rawvideo',
        '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
        '-s', '1000x1000',
        '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24',
        '-r', '24',
        '-an',
        '-vcodec', 'mpeg',
        'my_output_videofile.mp4' ]
call(command)
```

This will look for images name image0.jpg, image1.jpg etc.

More here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion! Sadly, it looks like that wasn't the only bug. I'm still getting the same error message, which is odd. Is there anything else that looks weird in my code? Thanks again!

Comment: The page you linked to was regarding piping an array of images into the ffmpeg call. I've updated to just use the `call` method. Also updated the order of the arguments as -i needed to be closer to the top for me.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the full path to `ffmpeg`:

```
FFMPEG_BIN = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg"
```

or wherever it is. Also make sure it's executable by running `chmod ugo+x`.

Also, as mentioned in the other post, your input is declared as `-`, which means that ffmpeg is expecting your to pipe raw RGB24 frames to it. Probably not what you want, unless your Python program does that (but I don't see it in your code).